# Python modify dictionary recursively

Tags: python, dictionary, recursion

I have a Python AST parser that converts expressions like `1==1 or 2==2 or 3==3` into this dictionary:

```
{ 'args': [ {'args': [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], 'function': '=='},
            {'args': [{'value': 2}, {'value': 2}], 'function': '=='},
            {'args': [{'value': 3}, {'value': 3}], 'function': '=='}],
  'function': 'or'}
```

This is then converted to JSON and POSTed to and API endpoint, however the API only understands binary `or` operations. So the pasted dictionary above needs to be converted (nested) into the following:

```
{ 'args': [ { 'args': [ { 'args': [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}],
                          'function': '=='},
                        { 'args': [{'value': 2}, {'value': 2}],
                          'function': '=='}],
              'function': 'or'},
            {'args': [{'value': 3}, {'value': 3}], 'function': '=='}],
  'function': 'or'}
```

Doing this from the Python AST is not possible because the `BoolOp` has 3 elements so I think it's best to do it recursively. However I can't visualize a correct way to achieve this iterating the dictionary in a recursive manner.

edit:

The dictionary can be deeply nested like:

```
{ 'args': [ {'args': [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], 'function': '=='},
            {'args': [{'value': 2}, {'value': 2}], 'function': '=='},
            { 'args': [ { 'args': [{'value': 3}, {'value': 3}],
                          'function': '=='},
                        { 'args': [{'value': 4}, {'value': 4}],
                          'function': '=='},
                        { 'args': [{'value': 5}, {'value': 5}],
                          'function': '=='}],
              'function': 'or'}],
  'function': 'and'}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
def _nest_ors(args):
    assert len(args) >= 2

    if len(args) == 2:
        return {
            'function': 'or',
            'args': args
        }

    return {
        'function': 'or',
        'args': [args[0], _nest_ors(args[1:])]
    }


def fix_ors(ast):
    assert ast['function'] == 'or'

    return _nest_ors(ast['args'])


expression = {'args': [{'args': [{'value': 1}, {'value': 1}], 'function': '=='},
                       {'args': [{'value': 2}, {'value': 2}], 'function': '=='},
                       {'args': [{'value': 3}, {'value': 3}], 'function': '=='}],
              'function': 'or'}

print(fix_ors(expression))
```

If you have really huge expressions, you will have to replace the recursion with an iterative solution.

Comment: doesn't work for me: the `ast` in `fix_ors` soon becomes a list of dicts and `ast['function']` throws a `TypeError`

Comment: Also, there is a call to `nest_ors` it should be `_nest_ors`

Comment: @Blender: Thanks, still returns an extra 'or', the outer one, that does not receive 2 arguments.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: Fixed

Comment: @Blender: Accepted your answer, however could you please advise on how to solve recursion for cases like the dictionary I added in the edit ? Some `args` might be of size 2, but inside one of those there may be faulted elements as well.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza: you'd have to traverse the entire AST to do that. You might be able to do that as you're parsing the Python AST and generating your own.